# Медицинская экспертная система

Tags: база-данных

Нужно написать программу, которая по введённым симптомам будет искать болезнь. Помогите с созданием кода. 
И подойдёт ли сюда БД SQLite?

Comment: подойдет sqlite или нет - а кто его знает. Все зависит от кода.
А вот код... я думаю, что тут подошла бы нейронная сеть. Но постановка задачи слишком уж общая.


А вот словарик русского языка был бы кстати:)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что подойдет любая БД, которую знаете, я бы использовал MySQL, так-как она бесплатная, а мой опыт работы с ней говорит, что работает она стабильно. Также могу предоставить код для работы с MySQL из Delphi.

Используется библиотека libmysql.dll.

Может не оптимально, но я делаю так и всё работает. Если кто делает лучше, дайте пример. Буду использовать.

```
uses
  MySQLAPI, MySQLAPIError;
...

var

  Con:PMYSQL;
  NameOfDB:string;
  Err:integer;
  Rez:string;
  Res:PMYSQL_RES;
  Row:MYSQL_ROW;
  result_base:integer;

...

function Zapros(query:string):integer;
begin
if Form1.Panel2.Color=clLime then
begin
    Result:=0;
    try
    mysql_real_query(Con,PChar(query),Length(query));
    result:= mysql_errno(Con);
    except
    end;
    end;
end;

function GetRecordStr(Str:string):string;
var TempStr:string;
    i:integer;
begin
if Form1.Panel2.Color=clLime then
begin
     //вид передачи
     Result:='';
     result_base:=mysql_query(Con, PChar(Str));
     Res:=mysql_store_result(Con);
     repeat
     if Res<>nil then
     begin
     Row := mysql_fetch_row(Res);
       if Row<>nil then
       begin
         TempStr:='';
         i:=0;
         try
         while i<1000 do
         begin
         if Row^[i]<>#0 then
         TempStr:=TempStr+Row^[i]
         else
         TempStr:=TempStr+'@';
         i:=i+1;
         end;
         except
         end;
         Result:=Copy(TempStr, 1, Pos('@',TempStr)-1);
       end;
       end;
     until Row=nil;
     mysql_free_result(Res);
     end;
end;

procedure CheckDBConnection;
begin
Con:=mysql_init(Con);
try
Con:=mysql_real_connect(Con,PChar(Form3.Edit1.Text),PChar(Form3.Edit2.Text),PChar(Form3.MaskEdit1.Text), PChar(Form3.Edit4.Text), StrToInt(Form3.Edit5.Text), nil ,0 );
NameOfDB:=mysql_get_host_info(Con);
if NameOfDB<>'' then Form3.Label6.Caption:='DB: '+NameOfDB;
if NameOfDB<>'' then Form1.Panel2.Color:=clLime;
except
Form1.Panel2.Color:=clRed;
Form4.Visible:=true;
end;
end;
```

В mysql_real_connect подставляются параметры соединения с БД.

Несколько примеров:

```
Dod_Info:=GetRecordStr('SELECT DISTINCT notam.original, notam.xxx, notam.yyy FROM notam WHERE (numb = "'+MassDod[i1]+'") ORDER BY icao_notam.date');
```

Пример:

```
CheckDBConnection;
```

Пример:

```
Zapros('UPDATE objekt SET active = "'+active+'" WHERE id = "'+TempId+'"');

Zapros('INSERT INTO objekt (number,imya,lon,lat,color,active,dod,dat,chas,id_dgerelo,date_podtv,chas_podtv,obj_type) VALUES ("'+Edit1.Text+'","'+ComboBox1.Text+'","'+Edit2.Text+'","'+Edit3.Text+'","'+IntToStr(Panel1.Color)+'","'+active+'","'+Memo1.Text+'","'+DateBeg+'","'+Chas+'","'+TempIdDger+'","'+DatePodtv+'","'+ChasPodtv+'","'+ComboBox4.Text+'")');

Zapros('DELETE FROM objekt WHERE id="'+TempId+'";');
```

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, если можете.

Comment: Здесь много кода будет, пишите на yuriy_buchinskiy@mail.ru